# Can I record what I see with VLC player?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have VLC player and see something, for example, internet IPTV stream.

Can I just record it by pressing record button?

I have record button and when I press it, it appear pressed, but nothing apparently happen.

I wish it create new video file in destination directory and save video to there.

Answer (score 3):

It records in your "Videos" folder on Windows. I have managed to record a YouTube video using VLC Player.

1. Open the YouTube video you want to record.
2. Copy the URL from your browser's address bar.
3. In VLC Player: Click Media -> Open Location From Clipboard (Ctrl+V)
4. Press Play
5. Press Record
6. After a few seconds press Stop.
7. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to your "Videos" folder in your user folder.  For example C:\Users\myname\Videos

I'm not sure if this will work for all video formats and streams.

Before you do this, you need to check that your Capture Device (Media -> Open Capture Device...) is set to "Direct Show" and that you view advance controls (View -> Advanced Controls).

Comment: I tried this and it works, yes you just press the record button.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Comment: Wow the resulting .avi file comes in at around 100MB per second