# How to disable all sounds except audio/video playback?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, video, system-sounds

Is it possible to disable all sounds in all applications (unknown list) in Windows during audio / video playback (one known application)?

When I am watching movie on my computer, dozens of disturbing sounds occur: mails come, messages come, events happen and so on.

Is it possible to disable all this in bulk?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but do you realize that you currently have over **100** open questions without an accepted answer?  Many of those queries have produced viable solutions within the discussions.  The subject matter experts within the Super User community might be more inclined to contribute their time and effort if you follow-up within most of your questions.

Comment: @Run5k I am accepting answers when they are correct

Comment: Sometimes, yes... but on many occasions you don't, and you often don't provide any feedback one way or another.  Here is just one example:  another community member confirmed that the proposed solution works, but you never posted again after the initial question:  [Can I record what I see with VLC player?](https://superuser.com/questions/1131659/can-i-record-what-i-see-with-vlc-player).  That was actually three months ago.

Comment: Sometimes I can't both confirm that the answer is either correct or incorrect. Then I wait for a long time and accept answer which is most voted.

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong... I admired your enthusiasm and dedication to the Super User community.  Having been awarded 22 `Famous Question` badges is quite impressive!  At the same time, I think it's possible that you become a bit overwhelmed with the sheer number of open questions that you have.  Even if you *"can't both confirm that the answer is either correct or incorrect"*, we probably shouldn't have questions where three months have passed without *any* feedback from the author.  There are other examples where you have solutions within minutes that are guaranteed to work, yet silence.

Comment: If I am not feeding back this usually means some sort of unsatisfaction, I am not just ignoring answers. Anyway feel free to comment any question you think I forgot about.

Comment: P.S. Also regard this very qstn: most probably we won't receive satisfying answers for this, because it is just windows bad design note in the form of a question...

Comment: If you aren't satisfied the the suggested answers, that's fine.  But please remember that you have numerous I.T. professionals who are donating their expertise, time, and effort in an attempt to help you.  Appropriate feedback (good, bad, or otherwise) should be a standard professional courtesy.  As I said before, we really shouldn't have questions where people have dedicated the time to propose potential answers, but the author hasn't provided *any* feedback comments for three **months**.

Comment: I don't agree. If some question has no answer by it's nature, it should remain answerless so that software designers see blind spots in their design.

Comment: If the question *"has no answer by its nature,"* that's fine. Do you really have over one-hundred questions that meet that criteria? I have my doubts. Regardless, I was emphasizing proper *feedback* for the Super User community members who are volunteering their time to help you, not the software designers. In that sense, I don't think that there is anything to disagree with. Standard courtesy and respect would dictate that we provide some type of feedback to the community members devote the time and effort towards helping you, rather than let a question go without any OP comments for months.

Comment: I can't guarantee that 100% of my unaccepted questions are of this nature, but most of them do. Beleive me that I am not just abandon my questions without a reason (in most cases). 

Feedback is often senseless, because people are often unable to accept it (and our talk here is a good example).

Comment: You're right, this discussion does provide a classic example of people who are unable to accept honest, constructive feedback. The bottom line is that while you still have over 100 open questions within the Super User realm, you continue to ask new ones without properly addressing your previous queries. Although your enthusiasm and dedication to the Super User community are admirable, you essentially abandon many of your questions. You solicit answers, but feel that posting feedback & reply comments to those same community members who offered to help you is senseless? That is unprofessional.